# Shopware slider banners not fully displayed

Tags: slider, shopware

I'm working with shopware 5 on my e-commerce website but the sliders and banners(as shown below) are not fully displayed..
Is there any solution for this?
I'm really new to this shopware

Thanks in advance
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add more information like css classes, code example etc.

Comment: It looks like you need to edit some styles

Comment: How do I add styles in shopware? That's the main issue actually

Comment: You could create a child theme and change the styles from there or can look if there is a plugin where you can add styles at the backend

Comment: thank a lot!! custom javascript/CSS did the work